# Mac keyboard beeps at login screen

Tags: keyboard, login-screen

I have a 2015 MacBook Air 13. Right after I let it sleep and reopen, I can't type the password as it only beeps when alphanumeric keys are pressed. It also beeps when escape, space, delete  or arrow keys are pressed.

It doesn't beep for keys like control or command, nor for the power button. But I can't even turn off the computer since holding down the power button for a long time doesn't do anything.

Previously the computer had an SMC problem and now I can't let it run out of battery to restart it. Any help appreciated!
(The SMC problem was that when it run out of battery I couldn't restart it again without doing a power cycle by unplugging the battery. So now I never let it die.)

Comment: Which SMC problem? Does the beeping problem disappear after a moment or can't you even log in right now?

Comment: The SMC problem was that when it run out of battery I couldn't restart it again without doing a power cycle by unplugging the battery. So now I never let it die. At the moment I can't login.

Comment: An "SMC problem" has the potential to affect every system on your Mac.  Alternatively, this could be completely unrelated to this keyboard issue.  I would try an *external* keyboard to see if the problem goes away, but in the end, you need to get your MBA serviced.  This is like telling your mechanic "I have an engine problem with my car so I never turn it off and now my transmission won't shift. Any ideas?"